# Group classification using semidirect product

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

This table says that every non-abelian group of order 12 is isomorphic to one of $A_4, D_{12}, Z_3\rtimes Z_4$.

But what does $Z_3\rtimes Z_4$ mean? Does this mean that "there is some morphism $\phi:Z_4\rightarrow Aut(Z_3)$ such that a group $G$ is isomorphic to $Z_3\rtimes_{\phi} Z_4$?

And here is another example.

> Rotman - Introdction to grp theory p.169
>
> Both $S_3$ and $Z_6$ are $Z_3\rtimes Z_2$

So I'm guessing this means that, depending on a morphism, $Z_3\rtimes Z_2$ is isomorphic to either $S_3$ or $Z_6$.

Am I guessing correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're guessing correctly. Observe that the automorphism group of $Z_3$ is just $Z_2$. So there are two automorphisms of $Z_2$ and $Z_4$ to $\text{Aut} Z_3$, giving a single nonabelian semidirect product in both cases.